# WPF DataGrid System.NullReferenceException

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I need some extra functionality in the WPF DataGrid so I am inheriting from it.

My code looks like the following

```
 public class GenericDataGrid : DataGrid
 { 
    public GenericDataGrid()
    {
       PreviewMouseMove += GenericDataGrid_PreviewMouseMove;
    } 
    private void GenericDataGrid_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e == null)
        {
          Log.Error(this, error);
        }
        else
        {...}
    }
}
```

With this code, at random times when i click on the Grid, i get the following error :

```
***System.RuntimeType - System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at LBG.PT.Common.View.Core.Controls.Grid.GenericDataGrid.GenericDataGrid_PreviewMouseMove(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e) in c:\BuildAgent2\work\fbe7560eaf130ae\Common\Grid\GenericDataGrid.cs:line 235
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)***
```

Any idea if this means that it is a Bug in the control itself?  If so how should i go about resolving the issue?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the error on my side. What is at line 235?

Comment: if(e == null) : it takes quite a lot of time and clicking and dragging etc. to make it happen.  But sometimes it happens very quickly.  I can't work out why or how that line of code could possibly fail.

Comment: any  updates on the matter/any fixes/workarounds? @caa